# Need help with some equivalent statements of measurability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

[image]

I want to know why the above statements are true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint 1: The family $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subset \mathbb{R} : f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra. (To prove this you must use $f^{-1}(\cup_i A_i) = \cup_i f^{-1}(A_i)$ and $f^{-1}(A^c)  = (f^{-1}(A))^c$. Note that in general $f(\cup_i A_i) \neq \cup_i f(A_i)$!)

Hint 2: Any of the collections mentioned ( such as $\{(-\infty, a] : a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ ) generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Hint 3:  If we assume $\mathcal{E}$ is a family of sets contained in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then by definition the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$ is contained in $\mathcal{A}$: $\sigma(\mathcal{E}) \subset \mathcal{A}$.